# Using Dynamic Row And Column in Range

Tags: vba, excel

Please can someone tell me where I have gone wrong with the code below?

```
Dim lastcol as Long, endrow as Long
lastcol = Cells(3, Column.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
endrw = Cells(Rows.Count, “B”).End(xlUp).Row

Range(“D4:” & Cells(endrow, lastcol)).Select
```

It is the last line that is causing `an error. 
endrow finds row 44
lastcol finds column N

Comment: Your posted code contains "smart quotes" - if those are present in your actual code you need to replace them with "regular" quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note; you declare the End Row variable as `endrw` and then use it as `endrow`, also you wrote `Column` instead of `Columns`.

In the last row you attempt to create a range from a predefined cell (`D4`) and have it expand to the newly identified cell. At the moment, you're trying to join the string `"D4"` with the Range object of the cell. Instead try;

```
Range("D4:" & Cells(endrow, lastcol).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)).Select
```

Or even better;

```
Range(Cells(4,4), Cells(endrow, lastcol)).Select
```

The first converts the new cell into a string address, the second just uses the Range object (cell) of `D4` instead of the string address.

All in all, it should look like this;

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastcol As Long, endrow As Long
    lastcol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    endrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(endrow, lastcol)).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `Range(“D4:” & Cells(endrow, lastcol)).Select`, more exactly this statement `“D4:” & Cells(endrow, lastcol)` will concatenate `D4:` with value of `Cells(endrow, lastcol)`, so it might be anything (it would be really lucky for that to form valid range :)).

Range can be specified using cells or by passing a string defining range , but both must not be mixed the way you did (as long as the cell doesn't contain some other cell address).

So you should write: `Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(endrow, lastcol)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in your code:

1. Columns - in the 2nd row
2. endrw - in the 3rd row
3. reference columns either by letters or by indexes

Try this variant instead:

```
Dim lastcol As Long, endrow As Long
lastcol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
endrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(endrw, lastcol)).Select
```